# How to compactly view JSON in IntelliJ / WebStorm?

Tags: json, intellij-idea, webstorm, intellij-plugin

When I've got a rather big JSON file I can easily view it in IntelliJ / WebStorm just like any other text file. But when it gets so large that I need quite a lot of scrolling to view it, it gets very hard to find and read the details I'm interested in.

A very simple solution would be a view where data is represented exactly like objects are shown in the IntelliJ JavaScript debugger. This is far more space efficient and opening/closing subbranches allow a very quick navigation.

Is there a way (e.g. a plugin?) that I can change the display of the JSON in IntelliJ / WebStorm in such a way?

(Note: I don't want to change the default view. But I'd like to say something like: show this file in object view. To be able to compare (sub-)content I need at least two files in object view mode)

Edit:
As a bonus it would be great when I could also show the difference of two JSON structures in such a view

Comment: Do you need smth similar to tree view? https://monosnap.com/file/ZAIn9gUFvUKcMGAvFr798okCqEEQPJ

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10650-json-parser

Comment: Ok, I checked that plugin: it goes in the right direction, but it isn't sufficient for me: it doesn't show a file, I need to copy the content of my JSON manually into the plugin space. And then I can see only one tree at a time. It's not possible to show two JSON trees at the same time so that I can compare subbranches relevant for me

Comment: Isn't it the Structure View is for?